# Pandas: create rows for each unique value of a column, even with missing data

Tags: python, pandas

*Note*: I had difficulty wording the title of my question, so if you can think of something better to help other people with a similar question, please let me know and I will change it.

## Current Data

Stored as a Pandas DataFrame

```
print(df)

week | site | vol
1    | a    | 10
2    | a    | 11
3    | a    | 2
1    | b    | 55
2    | b    | 1
1    | c    | 69
2    | c    | 66
3    | c    | 23
```

**Notice that site b has no data for week 3**

## Goal

```
week | site | vol
1    | a    | 10
2    | a    | 11
3    | a    | 2
1    | b    | 55
2    | b    | 1
3    | b    | 0
1    | c    | 69
2    | c    | 66
3    | c    | 23
```

Essentially, I want to create rows for all of the unique combinations of `week` and `site`. If the original data doesn't have a `vol` for a `week-site` combo, then it gets a `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `stack` with `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['week','site']).unstack('week',fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
Out[424]: 
  site  week  vol
0    a     1   10
1    a     2   11
2    a     3    2
3    b     1   55
4    b     2    1
5    b     3    0
6    c     1   69
7    c     2   66
8    c     3   23
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea how this sequence of methods work, so I have some research to do, but the solution works.

Comment: @NLR Yw : -) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You can use `crosstab` and `stack`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.site,df.week,df.vol, aggfunc='first').fillna(0).stack().reset_index(name='vol')
```

Output:

```
  site  week   vol
0    a     1  10.0
1    a     2  11.0
2    a     3   2.0
3    b     1  55.0
4    b     2   1.0
5    b     3   0.0
6    c     1  69.0
7    c     2  66.0
8    c     3  23.0
```